# Email href querystring params shuffled when "delivered" to clients

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, html-email, sendgrid, urlencode

We are having a weird querystring params shuffling problem and we dont have any clue about a possible solution.

Having the url `https://foobartracking.com/route/path?p1=638cc40ea7bb55fe4f6a79d6&p2=636bb902ee70eb000888ee65&email=test@email.com` insert into an html email, we expect our servers (foobartracking) to receive querystring param `p1=638cc40ea7bb55fe4f6a79d6` and `p2=636bb902ee70eb000888ee65`

Instead, we receive the querystring param `p1=961dd73fb0cc88af7a9b02e9` and `p2=969cc235ff03fc333111ff98`.
Moreover, `email` querystring param get shuffled only for the `local-part` and not the `@domain` part

We are using sendgrid & greenarrow saas to send emails. All of our emails to @icloud or @gmail are sent by sendgrid. All the rest of our emails are sent by greenarrow.

Our observations

1. `p1` & `p2` QS param shuffling is constant, it follows some kind of "we dont know what" but it's constant
2. From our log sample, none of the emails sent to @icloud or @gmail get QS params shuffling
3. From our log sample, most of shuffled email local-part are from `edu` or some kind of governement agencies all around the world
4. Never the `@domain` part of the `email` QS param get shuffled
5. Our email charset header and html charset header are set to `utf-8`
6. We activated some debugging in greenarrow that logs the received email and the sent email from their platform. There seems to be no problem as incoming and outgoing content of the email remains the same

Comment: so everything other than icloud and gmail have this problem? Sounds like greenarrow saas is changing it

Comment: @Nathan, I forgot to list an observation. We activated some debugging in green arrow that logs the received email and the sent email from their platform. There seems to be no encoding problem. I’ll edit the post